# Jenkins change-assembly-version-plugin can't change assembly version number?

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-assembly

I using jenkins to build the solution,I want to change the assembly version by [`change-assembly-version-plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+Assembly+Version).but there is no effect.

I found the same question [**“AssemblyInfo” MSBuild task failing in Jenkins build**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496781/how-to-set-assembly-version-to-jenkins-build-number) but there is no effect too.

Please give me hand to solve the problem.Thanks

---

**AssemblyInfo.cs in Solution Folder**:

[image]

**the source code is got every build.**

**Settings in jenkins**:

[image]

Build output :

```
14:38:40 Finished getting version 'C14319'. Retrieved 699 resources.
14:38:40 Changing the file(s) *SharedAssemblyInfo.cs to version : 26
```

Comment: Did you add a link to SharedAssemblyInfo.cs in your projects? Did you have to remove the line `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]` from the AssemblyInfo.cs files of your projects?

Comment: @BernhardHiller I Remove all info  which in the `SharedAssemblyInfo.cs `  from ` AssemblyInfo.cs `. I build the solution using VS2015,and all assembly fileversion was changed as `SharedAssemblyInfo.cs ` assigned.

Comment: @BernhardHiller I don't know why can't find the `AssembyInfo.cs` or `SharedAssemblyInfo.cs` can't find by **change-assembly-version-plugin.**

Comment: Then you likely did the basic steps correctly. Since I do not use that plugin but a small executable which I wrote myself for that purpose, I cannot give further hints.